# How can I get the C++ source code of a package on CRAN?

Tags: c++, r, cran

I am interested in the source code of the package https://rdrr.io/cran/fclust/, particularly the functions `RI.F` and `ARI.F`, but could only find the R implementations

- https://rdrr.io/cran/fclust/src/R/RI.F.R
- https://rdrr.io/cran/fclust/src/R/ARI.F.R

which are just link to the C++ code. Where is the source code of the C++ parts of a package usually available? Where in this case?

I am not sure if the package is Open Source to be honest and I am not sure if there is a place where the source code is "usually available".

Comment: https://github.com/cran/fclust/tree/master/src

Comment: @rawr: Thanks, I was not aware of that github repository! The link to the respective file is https://github.com/cran/fclust/blob/master/src/partition_comp.cpp

Answer (score 1):

*I explain how to do it for fclust, but instead of just providing a link, I show the path to get there in such a way that it should be reproducible for many other packages at CRAN.*

When you go to https://rdrr.io/cran/fclust/ then you see the table entry "Package repository" and behind it a link called "View on CRAN". When you go there and look underneath "Downloads:" you will see a link behind "Package source:". The source code is in the ".tar.gz".

Next, you have to look into the R-code and will see that the function `partition_comp` is called. You can also see it listed in https://rdrr.io/cran/fclust/f/ as `src/partition_comp.cpp`. So go into the ".tar.gz"-file and look for that file. It will contain the C++ source code.